Why a $\Gamma$ for the general semiaffine group in its notation?
This question is about notation.
I often see the general semiaffine group of degree $n$ over a field $K$ written as $A\Gamma L(n,K)$, $\Gamma A(n,K)$, $A\Gamma L_n(K)$, or $\Gamma A_n(K)$...
Why the use of the letter $\Gamma$? How did this notation originate?

Just guessing: because $\Gamma$ is $G$ in various languages and this is meant to be a variant of $\mathrm{AGL}$ etc.
